# Junit test cases

Tags: java, maven, junit

I am writing test cases for this code.

But I am not able to write junit test cases for this. I am having problem to write junit test cases for this.

Please help to write mockito or junit test case for this.

```
public class BasicCacheManager implements CacheManager {
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, BasicCache> cacheMap;
private String defaultCache;

public BasicCacheManager() {
    this.cacheMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, BasicCache>();
}

public BasicCacheManager(List<String> cacheNames) {
    this.cacheMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, BasicCache>();
    addCache(cacheNames);
}

@Override 
public BasicCache getCache(){
    return getCache(defaultCache);
}

@Override 
public BasicCache getCache(String name) {
    return cacheMap.get(name);
};

@Override 
public void addCache(BasicCache cache) {
    cacheMap.put(cache.getName(), cache);
};

@Override 
public void removeCache(String name) {
    cacheMap.remove(name);
};

@Override 
public void removeAll() {
    cacheMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, BasicCache>();
};

@Override 
public boolean cacheExists(String name) {
    return cacheMap.containsKey(name);
};

@Override 
public void removeElement(String cacheName, String element){
    BasicCache cache = getCache(cacheName);
    if(cache != null){
        cache.remove(element);
    }
}

// added final to avoid any child classes from overriding this method
private final void addCache(List<String> cacheNames) {
    for (String cacheName : cacheNames) {
        BasicCache cache = new BasicCache(cacheName);
        addCache(cache);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you detail what problems you're having?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need mocking here.

Your CUT (class under test) has very clear semantics; and interfaces that basically *guide* you into writing testcases. What you have to do: create objects of your cache class; and then use its methods to modify it; and asserts to verify.

Example:

```
@Test
public void testNewCacheIsEmpty() {
  BasicCache underTest = new BasicCache();
  assertThat(underTest.isEmpty(), is(true));
```

}

(in case you dont have an isEmpty() yet, you could add that one as package-protected method; just to allow for such tests).

Then you write other tests; for example that make sure that adding a certain cache-key ... actually does what you expect that to do.

So, the **primary** thing to understand here: you should design your whole cache so that you can test it ... without knowing what exactly it is doing.

Of course, you could create a **mocked** ConcurrentHashMap object and pass that into your class; to verify that exactly those calls that you expect for some operation to take place really happen. But that means: testing implementation details. And you want to avoid that if possible.

And just for the record: your field *defaultCache* doesn't make any sense in the code you are showing. It is null initially, there is no setter for it; so it has absolutely **no** purpose.